# Java basic term to describe given library/package

Tags: java

This is not a programming question, rather a term question.

What terms can be used to describe the statement:

```
import java.util.LinkedList
```

Did I import 'default' Java LinkedList API or package or class?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You used a [*single-type import declaration*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.1) to import the `LinkedList` class. (It's part of the `java.util` package, but you only imported a single type.)

Answer (score 1):

That is an import statement for java's standard LinkedList class. The `java.util` package is also called the Utility Package

Answer (score 1):

You made a class with name "LinkedList" resided in package with name "java.util" be accessible in your class.

When java runtime loads a class it verifies that all imported classes are loaded and initialized (their static blocks) before this class.